# unable to return string

Tags: c, string, return

the output should only return string by keeping only 2 same letters in the string.

example input: `aaaabbbbaaaa`
output: `aabbaa`
in this code, I'm unable to return a recreated string in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *solve(char *s) {
    char str[10];
    int x = strlen(s);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[i + 1]) {
            str[j] = s[i];
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        if (s[i] == s[i + 2]) {
            str[j] = s[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
   int t = 1, count = 1;
   while (t >= count) {
       char arr[10] = "aaabaaaa";
       printf("Case #%d: %s\n", count, solve(arr));
       count++;
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot return a pointer to a local variable. After `solve` returns, `str` ceases to exist, so its address is meaningless.

Comment: That being said, you must be aware that unlike in other languages in C there is no real string type. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. ( for `gcc`, at a ionimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Answer (score 3):

One major reason you are running into a problem is that you are attempting to return a pointer to a variable that is allocated on the stack.

When you define a local variable in a function and that variable is not marked as `static`, the typical strategy is to allocate that value on the stack.  When you are returning something that is passed by value (like an integer) this isn't a big deal, but when you return a pointer, which is effectively what `str char[10]` is, you are now returning the value of a pointer to something on the stack.

That value should be assumed to be unsafe, as it will almost certainly be overwritten shortly after the return, possibly even immediately since the variable has gone out of scope.

You would be better off passing in a second pointer that points to memory allocated by the parent function and copying your resulting string there.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return a pointer to a local variable. After `solve` returns, `str` ceases to exist, so its address is meaningless.  You an either allocate it on the heap (eg via `malloc`) or pass storage from main.  eg:

```
void solve(const char *s, char *str){
...    
}
int main(void)
{
   int t=1, count = 1 ;
   while (t>=count){
        char arr[10] = "aaabaaaa";
        char ret[sizeof arr];
        solve(arr, ret);
        printf("Case #%d: %s\n",count, ret));
        count++;
   }
}
```

Your current code does not seem to add a null terminator to `str`. Make sure you add that with `str[x] = '\0'`, and be sure you don't reference `s[i]` for `i >= sizeof s`.  The `s[i+2]` is potentially a problem (eg, will lead to undefined behavior) for i >= 8.

Also note that in this case it seems highly likely that the "solution" could be written back into the original string (you could solve this problem "in-place"), so there's really no need for the additional buffer at all.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a pointer to an object defined locally with automatic storage (such as `str` in `solve()`) has undefined behavior because the object is no longer accessible when the function returns.

There are multiple ways to address this issue for your purpose:

- you can modify the string in place, assuming it is modifiable.
- you can allocate a new string with `malloc()`, construct the modified string in it and return the pointer.
- a pointer to a target array can be passed to `solve()` for it so construct the modified string into.

For the second and third options, the target array must be large enough, and for all options, the modified string must be correctly null terminated, which is another problem in your code.

Here is a modified version with the simple approach of modifying the string in place, using the 2 finger approach: using a different index to read and write to the `char` array, which you implemented correctly except for the second test and the missing null terminator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *solve(char *s) {
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (s[i] != s[i + 1] || s[i] != s[i + 2]) {
            s[j++] = s[i];
        }
    }
    /* set the null terminator: necessary if the string was shortened. */
    s[j] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main() {
    const char *tests[] = {
        "",
        "a",
        "aa",
        "aaa",
        "aaab",
        "aaabb",
        "aaabbb",
        "aaabaaaa",
        "aaaabbbbaaaa",
        "ababababa",
    };
    int i, n = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char arr[20];
        strcpy(arr, tests[i]);
        printf("Case #%d: \"%s\" -> ", i + 1, arr);
        printf("\"%s\"\n", solve(arr));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Case #1: "" -> ""
Case #2: "a" -> "a"
Case #3: "aa" -> "aa"
Case #4: "aaa" -> "aa"
Case #5: "aaab" -> "aab"
Case #6: "aaabb" -> "aabb"
Case #7: "aaabbb" -> "aabb"
Case #8: "aaabaaaa" -> "aabaa"
Case #9: "aaaabbbbaaaa" -> "aabbaa"
Case #10: "ababababa" -> "ababababa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, for completeness sake. This one:

- Allocates memory inside of the function.
  This is, arguably, the best place to do it since only this function knows how much memory the result will take. More advanced implementations could, e.g., use `realloc` or first scan the input to determine the length of the output string.
- Is a more general solution, being able to change the number of allowed repetitions by changing one constant.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *solve(char const * restrict s)
{
    unsigned const numberOfEqualCharsMax = 2U;

    // The output string will be maximally as large as the input string
    size_t sSize = strlen(s);
    char *str = (char*) malloc(sSize + 1U); // +1 for the '\0'
    if (!str)
        return NULL;

    str[0] = s[0]; // Either copy the first char, or '\0'

    // Handle the empty string. Already copied '\0', now return
    if (sSize == 0)
        return str;

    // Handle |sSize| > 0
    size_t idxOut = 1U;
    unsigned numberOfEqualChars = 1U;
    for (size_t idx = 1U; idx < sSize; ++idx)
    {
        if (s[idx - 1] == s[idx])
            ++numberOfEqualChars;
        else
            numberOfEqualChars = 1U;

        if (numberOfEqualChars <= numberOfEqualCharsMax)
            str[idxOut++] = s[idx];
    }

    str[idxOut] = '\0';
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
   char arr[] = "ababaabbaaabbbabbaaba";
   char *solution = solve(arr);
   if (!solution)
   {
       printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   printf("%s\n", solution);
   free(solution);
}
```

Note that now `main` has to decide how to handle a failed allocation by `solve`.